# Back button using Extjs 3.4 History with ie8 & ie9 standards document mode

Tags: extjs

I am having a problem with Ext.History utility (version 3.4.0) working properly in IE8+.  It works in Quirks mode, but not with the document mode in IE8 Standards mode (IE8) or IE9 Standards mode (IE9).  Quirks mode isn't working for us because it is not rendering our CSS properly.

I have stripped everything out of the app except the history utility and now have two files (besides the extjs files):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>

<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <div align="center">
        <table width="97%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#link1">Link1</a> |
                    <a href="#link2">Link2</a> |
                    <a href="#link3">Link3</a> |
                    <a href="#link4">Link4</a> |
                    <a href="#link5">link5</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Fields required for history management -->
<form id="history-form" class="x-hidden">
    <input type="hidden" id="x-history-field"/>
    <iframe id="x-history-frame"></iframe>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

myapp.js:

```
Ext.ns('MyApp');

Ext.onReady(function()
{
Ext.History.init();
    Ext.History.on('change', function(token){}, this);
});
```

When I load the app in a web server, go to index.html, and click link1, the address bar shows #link1.  I then click link2 and the address bar shows #link2.  I then click link3 and the address bar shows #link3.

Using the back button in IE with IE7 Emulation, in Chrome or in Firefox, the address bar will go from #link3 to #link2.  When I hit the back button a second time, the address bar goes from #link2 to #link1.  This is the behavior I expect.

However, using IE8 or IE 9 in the appropriate document standards mode, when I click the back button a second time, the address bar goes from #link2 back to #link3.  Further clicks of the back button will just toggle the user between #link2 and #link3.  This behavior is unexpected and is causing our application not to work properly.

Note that this is the way that the Sencha example works for 3.4.0:

[Sencha 3.4 Sample](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/history/history.html)

(the page renders in Quirks mode, but if you change it to IE8 Standards or IE9 Standards, it doesn't work).

It does work seem to work properly in 4.1:

(only let me posts 2 links, but you can probably find it...)

I don't have access to Ext 3.4.1, but this issue isn't listed as in the bug fixes.  I have seen one thread ([here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?81393-Unpredictable-behavior-of-Ext.History-and-back-button-on-IE)) that suggests that changing the doctype would work, but that doesn't seem to be the case (I have tried all the doctypes...).

Note that many parts of our app are using the History utility for navigation, so removing it is not an acceptable solution.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it:

I created a new patch javascript file and included it after the ext files

```
/*
 @Author: RWR 20130224

 This fixes the issue with backward traversal of history in IE8 & higher in standard document mode.

 This class was challenging to override (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?46306-Help-How-to-extend-Ext.History)
 I ended up pasting all of the source original code here and making the necessary changes.

 NOTE that this may be patched in version 3.4.1.  It is definitely patched in 4.1.  When upgrading, validate that this patch is still required.
 */
NewHistory = (function () {
var iframe, hiddenField;
var ready = false;
var currentToken;
var oldIEMode = Ext.isIE6 || Ext.isIE7 || !Ext.isStrict && Ext.isIE8;

function getHash() {
    var href = location.href, i = href.indexOf("#"),
        hash = i >= 0 ? href.substr(i + 1) : null;

    if (Ext.isGecko) {
        hash = decodeURIComponent(hash);
    }
    return hash;
}

function doSave() {
    hiddenField.value = currentToken;
}

function handleStateChange(token) {
    currentToken = token;
    Ext.History.fireEvent('change', token);
}

function updateIFrame (token) {
    var html = ['<html><body><div id="state">',Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(token),'</div></body></html>'].join('');
    try {
        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        doc.open();
        doc.write(html);
        doc.close();
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function checkIFrame() {
    if (!iframe.contentWindow || !iframe.contentWindow.document) {
        setTimeout(checkIFrame, 10);
        return;
    }

    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var elem = doc.getElementById("state");
    var token = elem ? elem.innerText : null;

    var hash = getHash();

    setInterval(function () {

        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        elem = doc.getElementById("state");

        var newtoken = elem ? elem.innerText : null;

        var newHash = getHash();

        if (newtoken !== token) {
            token = newtoken;
            handleStateChange(token);
            location.hash = token;
            hash = token;
            doSave();
        } else if (newHash !== hash) {
            hash = newHash;
            updateIFrame(newHash);
        }

    }, 50);

    ready = true;

    Ext.History.fireEvent('ready', Ext.History);
}

function startUp() {
    currentToken = hiddenField.value ? hiddenField.value : getHash();

    if (oldIEMode) {
        checkIFrame();
    } else {
        var hash = getHash();
        setInterval(function () {
            var newHash = getHash();
            if (newHash !== hash) {
                hash = newHash;
                handleStateChange(hash);
                doSave();
            }
        }, 50);
        ready = true;
        Ext.History.fireEvent('ready', Ext.History);
    }
}

return {
    /**
     * The id of the hidden field required for storing the current history token.
     * @type String
     * @property s
     */
    fieldId: 'x-history-field',
    /**
     * The id of the iframe required by IE to manage the history stack.
     * @type String
     * @property s
     */
    iframeId: 'x-history-frame',

    events:{},

    /**
     * Initialize the global History instance.
     * @param {Boolean} onReady (optional) A callback function that will be called once the history
     * component is fully initialized.
     * @param {Object} scope (optional) The scope (<code>this</code> reference) in which the callback is executed. Defaults to the browser window.
     */
    init: function (onReady, scope) {
        if(ready) {
            Ext.callback(onReady, scope, [this]);
            return;
        }
        if(!Ext.isReady){
            Ext.onReady(function(){
                Ext.History.init(onReady, scope);
            });
            return;
        }
        hiddenField = Ext.getDom(Ext.History.fieldId);
        if (oldIEMode) {
            iframe = Ext.getDom(Ext.History.iframeId);
        }
        this.addEvents(
            /**
             * @event ready
             * Fires when the Ext.History singleton has been initialized and is ready for use.
             * @param {Ext.History} The Ext.History singleton.
             */
            'ready',
            /**
             * @event change
             * Fires when navigation back or forwards within the local page's history occurs.
             * @param {String} token An identifier associated with the page state at that point in its history.
             */
            'change'
        );
        if(onReady){
            this.on('ready', onReady, scope, {single:true});
        }
        startUp();
    },

    /**
     * Add a new token to the history stack. This can be any arbitrary value, although it would
     * commonly be the concatenation of a component id and another id marking the specifc history
     * state of that component.  Example usage:
     * <pre><code>
     // Handle tab changes on a TabPanel
     tabPanel.on('tabchange', function(tabPanel, tab){
     Ext.History.add(tabPanel.id + ':' + tab.id);
     });
     </code></pre>
     * @param {String} token The value that defines a particular application-specific history state
     * @param {Boolean} preventDuplicates When true, if the passed token matches the current token
     * it will not save a new history step. Set to false if the same state can be saved more than once
     * at the same history stack location (defaults to true).
     */
    add: function (token, preventDup) {
        if(preventDup !== false){
            if(this.getToken() == token){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (oldIEMode) {
            return updateIFrame(token);
        } else {
            location.hash = token;
            return true;
        }
    },

    /**
     * Programmatically steps back one step in browser history (equivalent to the user pressing the Back button).
     */
    back: function(){
        history.go(-1);
    },

    /**
     * Programmatically steps forward one step in browser history (equivalent to the user pressing the Forward button).
     */
    forward: function(){
        history.go(1);
    },

    /**
     * Retrieves the currently-active history token.
     * @return {String} The token
     */
    getToken: function() {
        return ready ? currentToken : getHash();
    }
};
})();
Ext.apply(NewHistory, new Ext.util.Observable());
Ext.apply(Ext.History, NewHistory);
```

Answer (score 1):

This was actually pretty straightforward.  I downloaded Ext 4.1 and looked at what they were doing with the Ext.util.History class.  They define a variable for oldIEMode and use that for all the conditionals where in 3.4 they are using Ext.isIE.

So I edited the Ext.History class in ext-all-debug.js and defined the following variable at the top:

var oldIEMode = Ext.isIE6 || Ext.isIE7 || !Ext.isStrict && Ext.isIE8;

There were three conditionals in the class that were checking for Ext.isIE which I replaced with oldIEMode.

I rebuilt and deployed the app and the issue was resolved.

Editing ext-all.js is not best practice, but I should be able to overwrite this class instead.